# Adding a circle to end of vertical line in plotly.js time series

Tags: plotly.js

I am using the Plotly.js time series with an added vertical red line (using shapes) like this:

```
Plotly.d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv", function(err, rows){

  function unpack(rows, key) {
  return rows.map(function(row) { return row[key]; });
}


var trace1 = {
  type: "scatter",
  mode: "lines",
  name: 'AAPL High',
  x: unpack(rows, 'Date'),
  y: unpack(rows, 'AAPL.High'),
  line: {color: '#17BECF'}
}

var trace2 = {
  type: "scatter",
  mode: "lines",
  name: 'AAPL Low',
  x: unpack(rows, 'Date'),
  y: unpack(rows, 'AAPL.Low'),
  line: {color: '#7F7F7F'}
}

var data = [trace1,trace2];

var layout = {
  title: 'Time Series with Rangeslider',
  xaxis: {
    autorange: true,
    range: ['2015-02-17', '2017-02-16'],
    rangeselector: {buttons: [
        {
          count: 1,
          label: '1m',
          step: 'month',
          stepmode: 'backward'
        },
        {
          count: 6,
          label: '6m',
          step: 'month',
          stepmode: 'backward'
        },
        {step: 'all'}
      ]},
    rangeslider: {range: ['2015-02-17', '2017-02-16']},
    type: 'date'
  },
  yaxis: {
    autorange: true,
    range: [86.8700008333, 138.870004167],
    type: 'linear'
  },
shapes: [{
    type: 'line',
    x0: '2016-10-16',
    y0: 0,
    x1: '2016-10-16',
    y1: 150,
    line: {
       color: 'red',
       width: 3,
       dash: 'dot'
   }
}]
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
})
```

which produces:

[image]

I would like to add a circle to the top of the vertical line (so a user can click on the circle).

I tried adding another shape object to the layout:

```
shapes: [{
    type: 'line',
    x0: '2016-10-16',
    y0: 0,
    x1: '2016-10-16',
    y1: 150,
    line: {
      color: 'red',
      width: 3,
      dash: 'dot'
    }
},
    {
      type: 'circle',
      xref: 'x',
      yref: 'y',
      fillcolor: 'rgba(50, 171, 96, 0.7)',
      x0: '2016-10-16',
      y0: 0,
      x1: '2016-10-16',
      y1: 190,
      line: {
        color: 'rgba(50, 171, 96, 1)'
      }
    }
]
```

The result in another line, rather than a circle, overlapping the red one like this:

[image]

Not sure what's going on.

NOTE: I attempted the approach from @mit in the comments, but this causes the circle to stretch upon zooming in, since the time delta used to creat the circle will obviously zoom with the time.

[image]

Comment: According to the docs (https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/shapes/#layout-shapes-items-shape-type), if `shape.type === 'circle'`,  "a circle is drawn from ((`x0`+`x1`)/2, (`y0`+`y1`)/2)) with radius (|(`x0`+`x1`)/2 - `x0`|, |(`y0`+`y1`)/2 -`y0`)|) with respect to the axes' sizing mode". Because in your case x0 and x1 are the same, your circle is so elliptic that it has become a line. Try picking two dates which are further apart to see what I mean.

Comment: I see what you mean. Unfortunately this will stretch the circle upon zooming-in to the visual, since the static datetime delta used to create the circle is being zoomed as well. See the GIF added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon this problem again and found a solution: You can circumvent the zoom problem by adding the circle as an SVG path.

```js
Plotly.d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv", function(err, rows){

  function unpack(rows, key) {
  return rows.map(function(row) { return row[key]; });
}


var trace1 = {
  type: "scatter",
  mode: "lines",
  name: 'AAPL High',
  x: unpack(rows, 'Date'),
  y: unpack(rows, 'AAPL.High'),
  line: {color: '#17BECF'}
}

var trace2 = {
  type: "scatter",
  mode: "lines",
  name: 'AAPL Low',
  x: unpack(rows, 'Date'),
  y: unpack(rows, 'AAPL.Low'),
  line: {color: '#7F7F7F'}
}

var data = [trace1,trace2];

var layout = {
  title: 'Time Series with Rangeslider',
  xaxis: {
    autorange: true,
    range: ['2015-02-17', '2017-02-16'],
    rangeselector: {buttons: [
        {
          count: 1,
          label: '1m',
          step: 'month',
          stepmode: 'backward'
        },
        {
          count: 6,
          label: '6m',
          step: 'month',
          stepmode: 'backward'
        },
        {step: 'all'}
      ]},
    rangeslider: {range: ['2015-02-17', '2017-02-16']},
    type: 'date'
  },
  yaxis: {
    autorange: true,
    range: [86.8700008333, 138.870004167],
    type: 'linear'
  },
shapes: [{
    type: 'line',
    x0: '2016-10-16',
    y0: 0,
    x1: '2016-10-16',
    y1: 150,
    line: {
      color: 'red',
      width: 3,
      dash: 'dot'
    }
},
    {
      fillcolor: 'green',
      type: 'path',
      xref: 'x',
      yref: 'paper',
      xanchor: '2016-10-16',
      yanchor: 1,
      ysizemode: 'pixel',
      xsizemode: 'pixel',
      path: 'M 0 0 C 10.5 0 10.5 -15 0 -15 C -10.5 -15 -10.5 0 0 0'
    }
] 
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
})
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

Unfortunately, plotly is quite picky with which kinds of path instructions it accepts, so constructing the right path is probably the trickiest part.